# How to determine the no. of integral partitions into $k$ parts?

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

I wanted to know, if I was to partition $500$ into positive $k$ integers, not necessarily distinct under the following constraints

1.k is +ve.

2.all k parts need not be distinct.

3.the first integer subtracted from the last integer in the k parts is smaller than or equal to 1.( a(k)-a(1)<=1)

what would be a formula for the number of possibilities?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: @Lord_Farin You have completely changed the meaning of the question in the title. Wouldn't it be preferable to ask the author for clarifications?

Comment: @O.L. I did this only after OP's edit of "$k$ integers" into "positive $k$ integers". I considered that a confirmation that fixed $k$ was the intended reading (for it was done _after_ your and Inceptio's answers were up).

Comment: @Lord_Farin Well without positivity the question is simply meaningless. Honestly I think it is better to ask Shobhit what was meant (again - I have no problem with deleting my answer if it turns out your interpretation was right).

Comment: @Shobhit Regarding the above confusion, could you provide the definitive answer on whether $k$ is fixed or not?

Comment: @Lord_Farin K is not fixed.

Comment: @Shobhit By that, you mean that the essence of the question is not changed if it says "to partition $500$ into positive integers" (i.e., omitting $k$, letting e.g. $500 = 499+1 = 498+1+1$ be two valid solutions)?

Comment: i am editing the question under constraints, on which i am currently working, any help is appreciated.

Comment: yeah the k parts need not be distinct.

Comment: i am writing the original problem please take a look.           A smooth partition of the integer n is a set of positive integers a1,a2,…ak such that 
1. k is a positive integer, 
2. a1≤a2≤⋯≤ak, 
3. ∑ak=n, and 
4. ak−a1≤1. 
Determine how many smooth partitions there are of the integer 250.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply have this expression

$$a_1+a_2+ \dots a_k=500$$

Now it's just a [Stars and Bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)  problem. *Assuming* $a_i$'s are all non-negative integers as Alex says. You have infinitely many ways to partition if you let *negative* integers.

Comment: Assuming the integers are positive, or at least non-negative. Otherwise this isn't a very interesting problem.

Comment: Yeah, works *only* for non-negative integers. There are infinitely many possible ways if you let *negative* integers in.

Comment: @arthur if u look at the third condition a(k)-a(1)>=0, but they are all integers therefore a(k)=a(1). or the answer is 500.

Comment: @user63477 if u look at the third condition a(k)-a(1)>=0, but they are all integers therefore a(k)=a(1). or the answer is 500.